# Find the 4th coldest hour in day

Tags: excel-formula, min

I have a sheet with 8760 records, one for each hour of the year.  In column A I have I have the date: 1/1/2017 01:00, and in column B I have the temperature for that hour.  In column C I would like to return the 4th coldest temperature from column B for each day.

Basically I'd like a MINIFS formula, but for SMALL.  So SMALLIFS.

SMALLIFS(Temp,hour=n,4)

Again, for each 24 hr day, i'd like the 4th coldest temperature.

Comment: So you want 24 rows of the 4th coldest temperature in colummn C for each day.

Comment: Yes that's correct.  I'll build other conditional formulas off of that, but that's the part I can't figure out.

Comment: I thought you wanted 365/366 rows of information  each row being a day and the value would be the 4th coldest corresponding to that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the the 4th coldest temperature for each 24 hr day,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 7, $B:$B/(INT($A$1:$A$8760 )=INT($A1)), 4)
```

I am unclear where you want the results. Seems like 24 identical results for each day is redundant calculation.

Comment: you can have unequal ranges within the array operation? or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, I did some experimentation to simplify aggregate 'cause I was tired of explaining things. There is no loss when the numerator is over-extended so returning row numbers can be row(A:A)/... instead of row(a1:a8760)/... Same with numericals like above.

Comment: That is an interesting little tidbit of information.  Thank you @jeeped!

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Can you tell me what the array portion of the function is doing?  B:B/(INT(A$1:A$8760 )=INT(A1))

Comment: It's creating a #DIV/0! error for every temp that doesn't match the day. The 7 (or 6 in @ForwardEd's formula) ignores errors. The 7 just ignores hidden rows as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your initial time is in A1  (ie no header rows).  Place the following in C1 and copy down.  each row will represent 1 day of the year.

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,($B$1:$B$8760)/(INT($A$1:$A$8760)=(INT($A$1)+ROW(A1)-1)),4)
```